# openCV 2.4.7 error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

Tags: c++, opencv, linker

i've got a Problem with a self compiled opencv...

XUbuntu 13.10 x64
gcc version 4.8.1

> cmake -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D
>   INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D
>   BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D WITH_OPENMP=ON ..

Everthing looks fine. Simple examples will be work.
My problem is, i want to use the nonfree(SURF) package in xubuntu.

Now i want to compile these example
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_detection/feature_detection.html
and get this error (Topic)

> g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include/opencv2 -O0 -g3
>   -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"example.d" -MT"example.d" -o "example.o" "../example.cpp" Finished building: ../example.cpp

Building target: SURF_Example
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker

> g++ -L/usr/local/lib -o "SURF_Example" ./example.o -lopencv_core
>   -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_nonfree

libopencv_features2d.so.2.4: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

Any help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably, problem is in incorrect linking order and missing lib features2d. Try

```
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -o "SURF_Example" ./example.o -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core
```

Comment: Ohhh my god, sorry... it was to late yesterday. 
Adding -lopencv_features2d solved the problem! THX

Comment: Good, hours dealing with same error. SIFT and SURF was removed on 3.0 so i need to compile 2.4 (somewhere says that you can compile 3.0 linking to opencv_contrib repo). Anyway if you just compile opencv 2.4.x and pointing to library features2d solved my issues thanks a lot

Comment: I had similar problem: ```libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line```, so adding ```-lopencv_imgcodecs``` worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with self-compiled OpenCV 3.2:

> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

It turned out my compiler commandline was wrong, too. The correct commandline became:

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags opencv` main.cpp `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

Please note that it is **g++**, not **gcc**, and compiler switches must come BEFORE your module, but linker switches must come AFTER, thus using **pkg-config** twice.