# Error: Undefined reference symbol to cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture(), DSO missing from command line

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to run my opencv code on raspberry pi but i get the  following error

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.o: undefined reference to symbol 'cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture()'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

Answer (score 0):

DSO stands for "dynamic shared object" so it's probably a linking error. See this: [openCV 2.4.7 error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19948723/opencv-2-4-7-error-adding-symbols-dso-missing-from-command-line)

Add `-lopencv_features2d` to your compile path.

Comment: i added this but I am still getting the same issue;(

Comment: There are many more libraries in OpenCV - make sure that you've added all of them to your compile path.

Comment: i have added all of these: opencv_core, opencv_highgui, opencv_imgproc, opencv_featured2d

Comment: let me know if im missing something

Comment: There are a bunch more: http://docs.opencv.org/master/, but you should try adding all of these: -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core . That should fix your problem.

Comment: -lopencv_videoio, not -lopencv_features2d.

Comment: thanx Berak this worked.. Im able to build my project now but when i run the program i get the following error:

Comment: VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L/V4L2: VIDEOC_S_CROP