# Compiler error when trying to link with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

`g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv4/ face.cpp -L -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui`

Error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cceoykhK.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN2cv12equalizeHistERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayE'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I get the following error while compiling. What should I do?

I added -lopencv_imgproc

```
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv4/ face.cpp -L -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc
```

error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccBOnCLF.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN2cv3MatC1ERKS0_RKNS_5Rect_IiEE'
    //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so.2.4: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried using

```
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv4/ -L/usr/local/lib face.cpp  -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core
```

Error:

```
face.cpp:(.text+0x5b): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture()'
face.cpp:(.text+0x179): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::open(int, int)'
face.cpp:(.text+0x188): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::isOpened() const'
face.cpp:(.text+0x1b1): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::operator>>(cv::Mat&)'
face.cpp:(.text+0x2e5): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture()'
face.cpp:(.text+0x3b5): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

done with

```
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv4/ -L/usr/local/lib face.cpp  -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core -lopencv_videoio
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19948723/opencv-2-4-7-error-adding-symbols-dso-missing-from-command-line

Comment: add `-lopencv_imgproc`

Comment: i added -lopencv_imgproc. Now I get following error->g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv4/ face.cpp -L -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccBOnCLF.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN2cv3MatC1ERKS0_RKNS_5Rect_IiEE'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so.2.4: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Don't comment your own answer. Provide some [mre] in your question

Comment: what is the correct order then?

Comment: See the link by @PaulR, it contains the answer to your question.